# Netlifyでデプロイが出来ているはずなのに表示ができない

Tags: git, node.js, vue.js, firebase, netlify

「M5Stack & M5StickCではじめるIoT入門」という本を読みながら勉強をしています。

本の途中で、Visual Studio Codeでビルドを行ってdistフォルダが作成されたものをNetlifyにドラッグ＆ドロップすることでコンパイルされWEBサイトが立ち上がるとあったので試験的にやってみました。

URLも作成されて無事に完成したかと思っていたのですが、ブラウザからアクセスすると
**「このサイトへの接続はセキュリティで保護されていません」** となってしまい閲覧ができません。
なお、VS Codeでビルドする前にnpm run serveをした場合、ローカル環境では正常に表示を出来ることが確認できました。

このような場合の対処法をネットで調べてみたのですが、これといったものにヒットせず困っております。
大変恐れ入りますが、どなたか教えていただけませんでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

アクセス先の URL が "HTTP**S**" ではなく `http://` の場合、最新のブラウザでは「保護されていないサイト」と見なされ安全のためにブロックされるケースがあります。

リスクを理解した上でブラウザの警告画面から該当のサイトに進むか (一般的にはお勧めしません)、
Netlify の場合には SSL 化する方法があるようです。

**参考:**
[Netlifyで公開しているサイトをSSL化する方法](https://note.com/koushikagawa/n/n23c0783bf05e)

> #### Netlify管理画面での設定
>
> - Netlify にログインし、「Domain management」から「HTTPS」をクリックします。
> - HTTPSの「Verify DNS configuration」をクリックします。

Comment: 返答が遅くなってしまい大変申し訳ありません。

Comment: 無事に出来ました。ありがとうございます。